# How can I make a installer for a large application use NSIS and 7z?

Tags: installation, nsis

I have a large application(more than 20G，many files and folders) on Windows platform, and I want to use "NSIS"(For some reason, I can only use it) to create an installer for it, just like what in the picture.[Installer and resource](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pIm1a.png)

it seems to pack the application folder as 7-zip multi-volume mode, and have a UI that can show the installation progress(or Decompression progress).

how can I achieve this?

Please tell me how to pack and unpack the files and folder with NSIS (and 7z plugin). It would be better if there is an example.

Thank you All!  ^_^

Comment: What is the specific problem? Show us some of your code...

Comment: @Anders   I am sorry, but I don't have any code yet.  I just want to know if NSIS can pack large files（more than 20G）to some .7z volume.  If so, how should I Write the script in a .nsi file。 Thank you!

Comment: NSIS does not support external files at all by default, depends on the plug-in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NSIS itself is limited to data that is compressible to <= 2 GB. Windows limits .exe files to 4 GB so no matter what you do you will end up having external files.

The Nsis7z plug-in only supports decompression. The idea is that you compress the data once with the normal 7-zip application and just bundle the .7z with the installer (on a DVD etc.)

```
InstallDir "$ProgramFiles\MyApp"
Section
SetOutPath $InstDir
Nsis7z::ExtractWithDetails "$ExeDir\BigData.7z" "Installing package %s..."
SectionEnd
```

You could also try the [NSISBI project](https://sourceforge.net/projects/nsisbi/), it has native support for giant external files.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it gave me a hint to use an external plugin. I will try it.